# Dialog asking "Update Dependencies from package.json" offers "Run 'npm install'" button, *after* I have already run my Vaadin 14.0.8 app successfully

Tags: java, node.js, vaadin, npm-install, vaadin-flow

I made a new Vaadin 14.0.8 web app using the "Plain Java Servlet" flavor on the Vaadin start page. I changed nothing in the POM file.

I ran the web app successfully from IntelliJ 2019.3 pre-release, after having first installed NodeJS/npm globally on my Mac Mojave machine. Good.

I quit. I restart IntelliJ. My project opens. Then this mysterious message panel appears in the lower left corner of IntelliJ window, asking: `Update Dependencies from package.json` with two buttons, `Run 'npm install'` and `Don't ask again`.

[image]

➥ What is the meaning of this question? What is required now that was not required when I successfully built and ran my web-app earlier?

➥ Why does it appear after I have already built, run, and re-opened my Vaadin 14 project?

➥ How should I respond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In Vaadin, ignore it

IntelliJ idea detects the presence of a `package.json` file and thus it determines you might want to install things via [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)).

Since the Vaadin project does this indirectly through Maven, you can **just ignore it**. Click *Don't ask again* button.